# Dynamically inserting directive using append() is changing the css behaviour

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to implement chat window and found [this working PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/CAfZziXPQD7OTeaVPMqX?p=preview). Although , my implementation is in very initial stage but I am facing on CSS behavior issue when I am adding new *chat-window directives*. [My implemented plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CkHUpAjUHj8ATz82fHYS?p=preview) here .

**Issue:**

My implemented plnkr works fine for *single chat window*, but as soon as second/third windows are opened, the minimising of chat windows changes from slid-down to slid-up.

Its surely because I am appending

`<div id="chat-space"></div>`

inside my directive by doing something like :

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('chat-space')).append(
    // trying to dynamically add the chat windows over here.   
    $compile("<div chat-toggle user-name="+scope.userName+" count='count'></div>")(scope)
 )
```

I think with little tweak in css, it can be resolved. Thanks !

Comment: Not too sure on the issue but just FYI, as your adding more chat windows you end up with multiple elements with the same ID `chat_window_1`. This is invalid HTML. Don't think that is your minimizing problem, but it is the cause of the issue when you click the `X` button.

Comment: @ste2425: Yep, i realised that too but for now its working as expected so I didnt look into it. May be I can handle that in `link` phase of directive to keep them independent

Comment: Or you can put that logic inside a directive and have angular deal with it, i guess angular will be involved in populating the messages so makes sense. If the chat window management must be outside of angular look into using more generic selectors. You can find the specific window using the event object.

Answer (score 0):

This is an html and css issue, i have edited your updated[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uF6RDdvNAR9QktQrPEj4?p=preview) and it is working fine as of now,

I added two new classes (below) to the target element of `chat-toggle`, problem was that every instance of `chat-toggle` was of same width as its parent element and thus causing irregularities, check out this.

```
.w50{
  width:50%;
}

.inline{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The chat windows are not staying at the bottom of page. Try opening 3 of em. They are also not equi-distant from each other. If you close some windows and open some again, you'll find that they all will be minimised by  clicking on any chat window

Comment: Nope, its not correct. Please open 3 chat windows  and try to toggle them.Also, they should all be at the bottom of the page.right now, they are appearing in the middle of the page

Comment: i think you can go ahead and make the things the way you wanted them to look,i was just trying to help you :)

Comment: Apologies if u were offended. Please refer the view which I am getting https://s14.postimg.org/4aelwlmqp/plunker.jpg . Thanks for your time. Cheers